# Can’t access remote FTP site from one PC, but it works on other PCs and Internet connections

Tags: ftp

I have problem with accessing a remote FTP server. I have asked help to hosting customer service and they said no problem on server side. Then I tried on my other PC (from my office), it working normal.

I followed this step [check blocked ftp](https://www.hostwinds.com/guide/see-if-blocked-firewall/) and get this message (the same message i got when try login from filezilla)

```
220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
220-You are user number 4 of 500 allowed.
220-Local time is now 00:44. Server port: 21.
220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
```

Speaking of FileZilla, I tried with WinSCP and have same result.
Tried create new ftp account and still not working.

I’m not sure when this issue happen. Previously I reinstalled Windows (I forgot if at this part I still have access to my server) then from my job I need to do some VPN thing with PuTTy or that cmd kind.

Two weeks later I realize I can’t access my server and thought it just me did wrong setup, tried reinstall FileZilla and reimport the sites and still no access to my server.

Need advice where is the source of problem? Or what I should check on my PC?

Log from FileZilla:

```
Status: Resolving address of ftp.xxxxxx.com  
Status: Connecting to 16x.6x.2x.1x:21...  
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...  
Response:   220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------  
Response:   220-You are user number 13 of 500 allowed.  
Response:   220-Local time is now 04:43. Server port: 21.  
Response:   220-This is a private system - No anonymous login  
Response:   220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.  
Command:    AUTH TLS  
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity  
Error:  Could not connect to server  
Status: Waiting to retry...  
Status: Resolving address of ftp.xxxxxxx.com  
Status: Connecting to 16x.6x.2x.1x:21...  
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...  
Response:   421 Too many connections (8) from this IP  
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

---

**UPDATE**: I have managed to use another connection for my PC and it working good. Now it shortened to my internet connection issue.

Any idea which part of internet connection that make this error? Connection setup, router, isp, or any other part?

Comment: what is the error? as the output you posted says that the server is reachable via ftp.

Comment: its stuck in that message and nothing happen. in filezilla it not showing folders of my server and stucked in Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...

Comment: as you said it work from your other PC, can you compare the settings used on both? and check the TLS settings as Muhammad suggested in his answer. Are you trying via IP or hostname? Are you trying the same way on both PCs?

Comment: i can confirm it same config both on my pc and my office pc. and both using latest version, 3.51.0. about TLS, i'm new with this one, is it the encryption option on filezilla site manager? i try using ip and host name, i tried all possibilities i know. and i have add log on my question for additional information.

Comment: yes, site manager, general, and compare the settings on both your PCs - I meant you to compare the settings on both PCs - config of connection settings. sorry I was unclear.

Comment: my office pc filezilla get latest version by update it, my 'problem' pc filezilla get latest version by install it. i have import sites.xml from my office filezilla. is it enough for called same? also i never change anything from my office pc filezilla since i installed it.

Comment: that sounds valid but unless you check the settings I cant know if they are the same or not.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you can try here. Check again using ACTIVE mode in FileZilla, and check connecting without TLS encryption. However, the best advice is to check your imported FileZilla sites/settings with the hosting customer service, or just ask them what settings to use. They'd be happy to provide it to you.

Comment: i have share my setting and even CS have create new account for me that work for them but failed in my pc. Active mode still not working. i try with "only use plain ftp" and its working but as it insecure i doubt i will use this config

Answer (score 0):

i still not found the main cause of this problem. after try several advices i can access again my ftp using this [1.1.1.1 vpn](https://1.1.1.1/). i still not marked this as the accepted answer but as long as this work to me i decide to put this on answer part. i hope someone still investigate or find the main issue based on this answer